# Centering a bigger image in a DIV

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to center (&crop) a big image in a smaller div. Here is how I want it to look like:
[image]

The image is simply centered to the div; it doens't matter how bigger or smaller the image is.

Any ideas?

Comment: you have to pass the image height width according to div  height width  if you are not useing image src or want to pass  through css then you  have to use background-size  css property

Comment: is it `<img>` in a `div`, or is it `background-image`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` combined with `position:absolute` to place it

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/400/sports/1/" />
</div>
```

and

```
.container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}
.container img {
    /*position it starting at the center*/
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;

    /*move it back by 50% of the image*/
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/4nH3A/1/

---

if you want to crop it as well, just add `overflow:hidden` to the `div` as well.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/4nH3A/2/

Comment: @xec chrome needs the `-webkit-` prefix for the transform properties (*`-webkit-transform` and `-webkit-transform-origin`*).. (*i only posted the standard ones*) - see http://jsfiddle.net/4nH3A/3/

Comment: Demo does not work for me as well, looks like transform-origin and transform: translate are not working for chrome

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use css `background-image`, this is quite straight-forward:

```
.box1, .box2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.box1 {
    /* 300x300 image centered in div (cropped) */
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
}
.box2 {
    /* 50x50 image centered in div (not cropped) */
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aWMLA/

Answer (score 0):

Try to stick at the standard CSS layout. There are going to be problems if you try to "run out of" elements using overflow:visible.

You should experiment with the HTML5 canvas: `drawImage()` is useful for both cropping and resizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image:center;
```

or

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: It's not what he's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
<div id="myimg"></div>
```

css

```
#myimg{width: 200px; height: 200px; background: url() no-repeat center; background-size: cover;}
```